# Connect to Android Device via Bluetooth Serial Port

Tags: network, bluetooth, android

I have been using Bluetooth Serial Port (BSP) at `/dev/tty.****` successfully in the past in order to communicate between macOS Big Sur (11.3.1, M1 processor) and Android (8.1).

However, when I want to connect my Android device to a new computer, pairing works but macOS almost never creates the `/dev/tty.****` device which makes the setup of a new machine very random. I noticed that the bluetooth device stays not-connected; if I force-connect it it connects for a few second then goes back to "not connected".

Files sharing works as well: in this case the bluetooth connects, the file transfers, then the bluetooth disconnects. And still I never see the tty device.

My question is:

- is there some configuration needed to be done on macOS or Android side to get the tty device?
- is there any other solution or tool I could use to communicate via Bluetooth with Android that does not depend on tty. I'm thinking for example a way to connect via MAC address, and send/receive data the same way I use the serial port

Note:

- the same tablet connects to Linux and Windows, but I need to use macOS.
- the same issue occurs with Fire OS 7.3.1.9 on Android side, as well as macOS Mojave (10.14.6) with an Intel processor.
- I currently use Python to read/write to the BSP, but I can use any command line tool / language in the middle (as long as it works with macOS Big Sur with a M1 processor)

Thank you.

Comment: What about ADB? It works over usb, LAN (WiFi), and if you can set it up, Bluetooth Pan (which is a Lan). It allows fast file transfers and allows changes to the Linux base of android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like macOS will only create the `tty` device if the Android app (that creates the serial Bluetooth service) is launched at the moment of the pairing.

If I pair first, and launch the app  **after**, then the device won't appear.
It won't work even if I disconnect and reconnect while the app is on. It has to be during the pairing.